Complete and sufficient statistic when only the maximum of the data is observed

I found the joint PDF, but I was unable to apply factorization afterwards.
How can i solve this problem?
The joint PDF is given by:
$
F(z, \Delta) = \left(f_X(z) F_Y(z)\right)^\Delta \left(f_Y(z) F_X(z)\right)^{1-\Delta} 
$
where $f_X(z)$ and $f_Y(z)$ are the PDFs of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and $F_X(z)$ and $F_Y(z)$ are the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$.

Hello. Show us your work first. Tell us your approach. I am sure people here would be willing to help then.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This ought to say $\theta_X$ and $\theta_Y$ rather than $\theta_x$ and $\theta_y.$

What did you find the joint pdf to be?

The joint PDF is given by:
$
f(z, \Delta) = \left(f_X(z) F_Y(z)\right)^\Delta \left(f_Y(z) F_X(z)\right)^{1-\Delta}
$
where $f_X(z)$ and $f_Y(z)$ are the PDFs of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and $F_X(z)$ and $F_Y(z)$ are the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$.

Then replace these functions by their respective expressions.
